# dont allow user to see image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I see this site [www.travian.com](http://www.travian.com) , this site for images make a list and call a function

```
var screenshots = [
                    {'img':'screenBig screenBig1','hl':'Village centre', 'desc':'Your village could like this one day, becoming the starting point for your vast empire.'},
                ];
```

in file i found

```
Object.each(screenshots, function (d) {
        a.addImg(d.img)
    });
```

then addImg function

```
var a = new Element("img", {src: "img/x.gif", "class": b, width: this.options.pimgwidth, height: 397}).inject(this.options.prev_items)
```

inject function

```
Element.prototype.inject = Element.prototype.inject.wrap(function (f, b, d, c) {
    var a = f(b, d, c);
    var e;
    if (typeof a != "undefined" && (typeOf(e = a.select("script")) == "array")) {
        e.each(function (g) {
            Browser.exec(g.text)
        })
    }
    return a
});
```

and in end exec

```
n.exec = function (o) {
        if (!o) {
            return o
        }
        if (g.execScript) {
            g.execScript(o)
        } else {
            var e = j.createElement("script");
            e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            e.text = o;
            j.head.appendChild(e);
            j.head.removeChild(e)
        }
        return o
    };
```

this is intersting to me that src of all images are src="x.gif" with 1px * 1px size , but show correct image, i follow code and i dont get answer to how do it 
I write code here that see anybody can help me to found how it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Travian.com](http://www.travian.com/), images come from css. The javascript code you listed is only creates `<img>` elements with specific ids.

You can use your browsers "Inspect Element" functionality to find this.

HTML:

```
<img src="img/x.gif" class="screen3" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
div#gallery img.screen3 {
  background-image: url(s/img3.jpg);
}
```